# Rails 4.2 flash not clearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

In a rails 4.2 app with sessions stored as cookies, I have the following code:

```
redirect_to (return_to || '/'), flash: { my_key: 'my values' }
```

It redirects with the values in the hash, but the flash data persists in the session cookie even after moving around across various actions. The data can be bulky, so it's important that it doesn't hang around and take up space. There is no `flash.keep` anywhere in the code.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
flash[:success] = "Success..."
redirect_to root_url
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.